# Sharing audio file with WhatsApp fails on Android 4.2

Tags: android, kotlin

I am failing to share an audio file with WhatsApp on an Android Jelly Bean emulator. My code currently works on Lollipop and higher versions but I couldn't figure out why this error occurs on lower devices.

```
    val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)

    share.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

    //Audio MIME type
    share.type = "audio/*"

    //File uri (from file provider on api level 24 or higher)
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri(context))

    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, context.getString(R.string.share_title)))
```

inside fileUri method

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24)
        return Uri.fromFile(this)
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.applicationContext.packageName
            + ".[myprovidername].provider", this)
```

logs

```
04-21 19:08:25.653 2840-2840/com.whatsapp W/Bundle: Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected ArrayList but value was a android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri.  The default value <null> was returned.
04-21 19:08:25.653 2840-2840/com.whatsapp W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
    java.lang.ClassCastException: android.net.Uri$HierarchicalUri cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Bundle.java:1223)
        at com.whatsapp.ContactPickerFragment.ga(:250573)
        at com.whatsapp.ContactPickerFragment.a(:249616)
        at c.j.a.u.a(:178380)
        at c.j.a.u.f(:178956)
        at c.j.a.u.a(:177973)
        at c.j.a.u.b(:178772)
        at c.j.a.u.j(:179098)
        at c.j.a.j.onStart(:246644)
        at c.a.a.m.onStart(:267332)
        at d.f.qJ.onStart(:296953)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Use the actual MIME type, not a wildcard.

Comment: I tried that too but nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

That's probably because WhatsApp is requiring a list of `Uri`s even if there's only one. Try returning something like this

```
ArrayList<Uri> uriList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uriList.add(Uri.fromFile(this));
```

Instead of

```
Uri.fromFile(this)
```

Comment: If so, that's a bug in WhatsApp. `EXTRA_STREAM` for `ACTION_SEND` is only supposed to be one `Uri`. `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` would be for multiple streams.

Comment: putExtra doesn't accept what singletonList returns share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Collections.singletonList(Uri.fromFile(toFile(context)))) won't compile

Comment: Since the error log indicates that it needs an ArrayList, that's the only plausible explanation, so I guess that's a bug in WhatsApp, I could be missing something and wrong though.

Comment: share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayListOf(fileUri(context))) like this? not working :(

Comment: I got it, just updated the answer, apparently you can't use `List` type

Comment: what do you mean? does it not compile?

Comment: it does compile but WhatsApp says it's failed and this time it's without those log messages

Comment: no, no related error messages on the logcat just a toast from whatsapp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192186/discussion-between-jackz314-and-lutfitekin).